# Fill a part of a Pandas Series with a value

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace a part of a `Series` in Pandas with a specific value, I'm not sure how to get around to that.

here's my series:

```
(Pdb) alfa = pd.Series(0, index=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
(Pdb) alfa
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
dtype: int64
```

I'd like to something like this:

```
(Pdb) alfa.fill([2,3,4], 5)
1    0
2    5
3    5
4    5
5    0
6    0
```

any clues?

Comment: alfa.loc[2,3,4] =5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do

```
alfa[[2, 3, 4]] = 5
```

or, if what you are dealing with happens to always be a contiguous range, cf. the documentation on [slicing ranges](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges),

```
alfa[1:4] = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.loc`:

```
alfa.loc[2:4] = 5
```

If you don't care about the actual value of the index, you can use `.iloc`:

```
alfa.iloc[1:4] = 5
```

**Note**: `.loc` will reference/set elements for indices between `2` and `4` inclusive.

Comment: `alfa.loc[2:5]` includes 5.

Comment: @dongiulio are you saying you want to set the second, third, and fourth value? In that case you `.iloc`.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for `replace` instead  `loc` `iloc` or slicing ..

Please look at the [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
>>> s
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64

>>> s.replace([2,3,4], 5)
0    0
1    1
2    5
3    5
4    5
dtype: int64
```

Note: In this sense your Indexing should start at default zero